# Google Speech API RecognitionConfig has no "speechContexts" field error

Tags: python, google-cloud-speech

I am using the latest Google-Cloud-Speech API (0.36.0). I am able to execute my script successfully, however, when I add the speechContexts parameter, I kept getting "ValueError: Protocol message RecognitionConfig has no "speechContexts" field." error.

I have followed the example on the Google Documentation page, but so far I have not making any progress.

**Source Code:**

```python
config = types.RecognitionConfig(
            encoding = enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
            sample_rate_hertz = 22050,
            language_code = 'en-US',
            speechContexts = [{'phrases':['installer']}]
            )
```

**Output**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
ValueError: Protocol message RecognitionConfig has no "speechContexts" field.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are the field `speechContexts`, while according to [the documentation for the `RecognitionConfig` class](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/speech/gapic/v1/types.html#google.cloud.speech_v1.types.RecognitionConfig), the correct name for this field is `speech_contexts` instead.

You only need to change your code above, to this one:

```
config = types.RecognitionConfig(
            encoding = enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
            sample_rate_hertz = 22050,
            language_code = 'en-US',
            speech_contexts = [{'phrases':['installer']}] #Note the change in the field
            )
```

You can refer to the [Python Reference for the Cloud Speech API](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/speech/gapic/v1/api.html) in order to have the complete documentation and examples of use for the client library.

Comment: Thank you! You are a life savior! I tried to add a reputation to your profile, but since my rep is fewer than 15pts, I will come back here when I have the 15pts and add the rep to your profile.

Comment: Hi @JieJenn, I am glad to hear that my answer was of help! In order to upvote, you [need the 15 reputation points](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) you mentioned, but in order to [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) there is no need to. So feel free to accept my answer if it was helpful for you, and in order to let the community know that your issue is solved. Thanks!